# Is there a simple function identify the sign of an expression given constraints

Tags: evaluation, simplifying-expressions

I'm looking to find a simple function that can identify the sign of an expression given a set of constraints. I have looked around and do see that there is a few threads on this but I'm not sure I understand them. As a bit of context (and I'm sure this is clear), I have never really used Mathematica before beyond some basic simplifications.

An example of what I want a function/command for is:

Given that $0<q<1$ and $0<y<x<1$, what is the sign of the expression $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{2q(2q+x^2-y^2)}{(2q(q-2)-x^2+y^2)^2}$ ?

```
 1/2 - (2 q (2 q + x^2 - y^2))/(2 q (q - 2) - x^2 + y^2)^2
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site.  I have [edited your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to include *Mathematica Code* in addition to you nice  $LaTeX$. In the future, please provide formatted code yourself. Read how to ask [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the conditions necessary for the expression to be [`Positive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Positive.html)

```
Assuming[0 < q < 1 && 0 < y < x < 1, 
 FullSimplify@
  Reduce[Positive[
    1/2 - (2 q (2 q + x^2 - y^2))/(2 q (q - 2) - x^2 + y^2)^2]]]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[2] + q == 2 || [...]
> ```

and other more complicated solutions.

If you need to know if that's always true then

```
Resolve[
 ForAll[
  {x, y, q},
  0 < q < 1 && 0 < y < x < 1,
  Positive[1/2 - (2 q (2 q + x^2 - y^2))/(2 q (q - 2) - x^2 + y^2)^2]
  ]]
```

> False

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.